# Unix: Locating service configuration files on the file system

Tags: services, netstat

I have a Solaris 10 box which has limited tools and commands installed in comparison to Linux distros. In addition, the tools that can be used such as grep and netstat don't have the same options and flags too.

I have some services running on ports that I would like to investigate. As an example, an SSH server running on a port that is not 22. I want to be able to locate the configuration file in order to modify changes (disable weak ciphers etc.). However, when I search the entire file system for `sshd.conf` - I am only able to find the configuration for the default SSH server on port 22.

Could anyone give me any tips on how I could locate the config file for this unique service. I have already attempted `find / -name "sshd.conf" and other possible variations but with no success.

The next approach I would like to try is using tools such as `netstat` and `svcs`. I can tell that the service is running with `nmap -p 5555 [ip]` and also `ssh [ip] -p 5555`. I can also see the service is listening with `netstat -an | grep "5555"`. However, I am unable to match it to a service listed in `svcs -a`. If I were able to match it with a service in `svcs -a` and then use `svcs -x [FMRI]` (for more details) - it doesn't give me the config file from where parameters are being read from - only the log file.

So TL;DR: How can I locate a service's configuration file if I know the FMRI or can't map the service to an FMRI. Perhaps more simply, how can I use the output of netstat and identify what the actual service is that is listening on the device? I would imagine this would be asked often for security audits and such.

Comment: netstat on Solaris 10 won't really help you map a port number to a process or service name. It will in Solaris 11.2 or later. https://blogs.oracle.com/casper/entry/solaris_11_2_user_pid

Comment: Yeah I got that impression from reading the netstat manual, thanks for the top about Solaris 11.2+

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could `man sshd`

That would tell you:

```
 -f configuration_file

     Specifies  the  name  of  the  configuration  file.  The
     default  is  /etc/ssh/sshd_config. sshd refuses to start
     if there is no configuration file.
```

And if you look at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` you'll see the configuration.

You can also do `man sshd_config` to see what other options are available.

In general, the XML source for services are in `/var/svc/manifest`.  The `ssh` one is `/var/svc/manifest/network/ssh.xml`.  You can view the current setting with `svccfg export ssh`.

Comment: Thanks, but the trouble with `man sshd` is that it only points to the ssh server at port 22 and not port 5555. However, the /var/svc/manifest is a new suggestion which I hope will return some positive results. One gripe with that though is that I only know that the port is running because of netstat and nmap - it doesn't actually tell me the name of the service - so in essence, my problem is `/var/svc/manifest/network/???.xml` - although perhaps I could grep for the port number in this directory? @Stephen Harris

Comment: If you have an `sshd` process that's not using the standard config then it _should_ show up in `ps -ef` and show the `-f` flag or the `-p` flag or similar.   Remember that not all processes may be started directly from `svcs` - an `sshd` could have been started manually or _another_ non-standard process started (eg a java based ssh daemon).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the things you suggested and I'll have a look into non-standard processes too. Thanks again for your input